# QGIS snapping to an offset outline

Tags: qgis, snapping

i'm facing a problem when it comes to snapping a line from one layer to an outline from a different layer

what i'm doing is drawing a polygon and i added another style to it and had it offset outwards from the polygon, and i want a line from another layer to snap to the outline from the polygon layer..not the polygon itself, i tried lowering the resolution of the snapping but it still doesn't snap to the outline just the polygon...any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a buffer polygon to snap the line to it. You can set the which layers to snap from `Settings -> Snapping options`, as follows:

[image]

1. Change the snapping mode to Advanced
2. Select the layers you need to snap. Set the mode to `to vertex and segment`, `tolerance` of 10 and `Units:` pixels. The OUTPUT.shp (in this example) is the buffer layer
3. Uncheck the layers that you don't want to snap to.

[image]